# Не работают функции JS на проде, на IISExpress работали

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

Проект ASP NET CORE MVC 3

В проекте в файлах представлениях я прописывал ссылки на файлы с JS функциями следующем образом:

```
    @section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/JS_Create_Edit_Friend.js"></script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

В самом файле прописывал:

```
// Обновление списка улиц после выбора города
$(function () {
    $("#CityId").change(function () {
        var formData = { 'CityId': Number.parseInt($('#CityId').val()), 'Name': $('#CityId>option:selected').text() };
        $.ajax({
           url: "http://localhost:18246/api/API/searchStreets",
            
            headers:
            {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'RequestVerificationToken': $('#RequestVerificationToken').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function (data) {

                dataFilling(data, 'idStreet', 'name', '#StreetId', '<option/>');

                // Генерация события для элемента Select
                let elemSelectHouse = document.querySelector('#StreetId')
                elemSelectHouse.selectedIndex = 0;
                const event = new Event("change");
                elemSelectHouse.dispatchEvent(event);
            },
            error: function (result, status, er) {
                alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

На локальном IISExpress при запуске все работало нормально, но при публикации на прод все сломалось, выдает ошибку, что :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (JS_Index_Friends.js:19)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

А перед этим предупреждение, что функции не определены:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/CollectVoters/js/JS_Index_Friends.js:19:23)
    at e (http://localhost/CollectVoters/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (http://localhost/CollectVoters/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
```

Поменял в функции абсолютный адрес на относительный:

url: "/api/API/searchStreets",

На тесте все работает на проде выдает ошибку, что не найден:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/api/API/searchStreets 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: `http://localhost` - это же прод, учитесь писать относительные пути, на проде у вас не локалхост. `url: "/api/API/searchStreets"`, то же самое в местах, где вы JS библиотеки подключаете.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, это уже упростило мне жизнь. Не знал, что так можно )

Comment: @aepot, вот те библиотеки, что на сервере их по относительной ссылке и подключал, но часть у меня с cdn: ```<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</environment>
```

Comment: `<environment include="Development">` - а для `Production` окружения не забыли? У вас библиотеки подключены здесь только у `Development` сборке. Еще в настройках смотрите, где у вас имя хоста задается, там нужно его на продовский поправить, но не в девелопмент конфигурации, а в продовской.

Comment: @aepot, я и не знал, нигде об этом особо не упоминается,  поэтому думал что в проекте все блоки, что нужны уже создались при создании

Comment: Всегда интересуйтесь, как и что работает. А если пишете для браузера, то интересуйтесь, как браузер работает. В противном случае ваш мир так и будет дальше похож на магию, которая всё для вас сделала правильно.

Comment: @aepot, оформите ваши подсказки в ответ, я отмечу и закроем этот вопрос

Comment: Вы можете сами его оформить и указать, что именно вам помогло.

Comment: @aepot, помогли оба комментария, которые я отметил. Сам ответ писать не хочу - это будет не правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Это же прод, учитесь писать относительные пути, на проде у вас не localhost. `url: "/api/API/searchStreets"`, то же самое в местах, где вы JS библиотеки подключаете.
- `<environment include="Development">` - а для `Production` окружения? У вас библиотеки подключены здесь только у `Development` сборке. В настройках смотрите, где у вас имя хоста задается, там нужно его на продовский поправить, но не в девелопмент конфигурации, а в продовской.